# Predicting the Trajectories of Planets Using Polyfit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm simulating the three body problem and graphed the trajectories in 3D. I'm trying to figure out how I can predict the trajectories of these planets by extending the plot lines using np.polyfit. I have experience in doing this with dataframes and on 2D plots, but not in 3D and without using any sort of dataframe. I provided the whole entire code and the extension attempts are below the graph, including the error message. I'm looking for any suggestions on how to modify my current code, particularly the portion of code that extends the plots, to make this work.
Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib inline

# Universal Gravitational Const.

G = 6.674e-11

# Defining Mass

m1 = 0.9
m2 = 3.5
m3 = 1.6

# Init positions in graph (array)

pos1 = [-5,3,1]
pos2 = [5,12,10]
pos3 = [-7,1,27]

p01 = np.array(pos1)
p02 = np.array(pos2)
p03 = np.array(pos3)

# Init velocities (array)

vi1 = [10,-2,3]
vi2 = [-1,3,2]
vi3 = [3,-1,-6]

v01 = np.array(vi1)
v02 = np.array(vi2)
v03 = np.array(vi3)


#Function
def derivs_func(y,t,G,m1,m2,m3):
    d1 = np.array([y[0],y[1],y[2]]) #Unpacking the variables
    d2 = np.array([y[3],y[4],y[5]])   
    d3 = np.array([y[6],y[7],y[8]])
    v1 = np.array([y[9],y[10],y[11]])
    v2 = np.array([y[12],y[13],y[14]])
    v3 = np.array([y[15],y[16],y[17]])

    #Distance between objects
    dist12 = np.sqrt((pos2[0]-pos1[0])**2 + (pos2[1]-pos1[1])**2 + (pos2[2]-pos1[2])**2) 
    dist13 = np.sqrt((pos3[0]-pos1[0])**2 + (pos3[1]-pos1[1])**2 + (pos3[2]-pos1[2])**2)
    dist23 = np.sqrt((pos3[0]-pos2[0])**2 + (pos3[1]-pos2[1])**2 + (pos3[2]-pos2[2])**2)

    #Derivative equations: change in velocity and position
    dv1dt = m2 * (d2-d1)/dist12**3 + m3 * (d3-d1)/dist13**3 
    dv2dt = m1 * (d1-d2)/dist12**3 + m3 * (d3-d2)/dist23**3 
    dv3dt = m1 * (d1-d3)/dist13**3 + m2 * (d2-d3)/dist23**3 
    dd1dt = v1 
    dd2dt = v2
    dd3dt = v3

    derivs = np.array([dd1dt,dd2dt,dd3dt,dv1dt,dv2dt,dv3dt])  #Adding derivatives into an array
    derivs3 = derivs.flatten() #Turning the array into a 1D array

    return derivs3 #Returning the flattened array

yo = np.array([p01, p02, p03, v01, v02, v03]) #Initial conditions for position and velocity
y0 = yo.flatten()  #Turning the array into a 1D array

time = np.linspace(0,500,500) #Defining time

sol = odeint(derivs_func, y0, time, args = (G,m1,m2,m3)) #Calling the odeint function

x1 = sol[:,:3]
x2 = sol[:,3:6]
x3 = sol[:,6:9]


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,15)) #Creating a 3D plot
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')

ax.plot(x1[:,0],x1[:,1],x1[:,2],color = 'b') #Plotting the paths each planet takes
ax.plot(x2[:,0],x2[:,1],x2[:,2],color = 'r')
ax.plot(x3[:,0],x3[:,1],x3[:,2],color = 'g')

ax.scatter(x1[-1,0],x1[-1,1],x1[-1,2],color = 'b', marker = 'o', s=45, label = 'Mass 1') 
ax.scatter(x2[-1,0],x2[-1,1],x2[-1,2],color = 'r', marker = 'o',s=200, label = 'Mass 2')  
ax.scatter(x3[-1,0],x3[-1,1],x3[-1,2],color = 'g', marker = 'o',s=100, label = 'Mass 3')

ax.legend()
```

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')

fit1 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x1[:,0],x1[:,1],7))
fit12 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x1[:,0],x1[:,2],7))
fit2 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x2[:,0],x2[:,1],7))
fit22 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x2[:,0],x2[:,2],7))
fit3 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x3[:,0],x3[:,1],7))
fit32 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x3[:,0],x3[:,2],7))

y1 = fit1(x1[:,0])
y12 = fit12(x1[:,0])
y2 = fit2(x2[:,0])
y22 = fit22(x2[:,0])
y3 = fit3(x3[:,0])
y32 = fit32(x3[:,0])

extended1 = np.linspace(x1[-1,0], x1[-1,0] + 300, 1)
extended2 = np.linspace(x2[-1,0], x2[-1,0] + 300, 1)
extended3 = np.linspace(x3[-1,0], x3[-1,0] + 300, 1)

yex1 = fit1(extended1)
yex12 = fit12(extended1)
yex2 = fit2(extended2)
yex22 = fit22(extended2)
yex3 = fit3(extended3)
yex32 = fit32(extended3)

ax.plot(x1[:,0],x1[:,1],x1[:,2])
ax.plot(x1[:,0],yex1,yex12)
ax.plot(x2[:,0],x2[:,1],x2[:,2])
ax.plot(x2[:,0],yex2,yex22)
ax.plot(x3[:,0],x3[:,1],x3[:,2])
ax.plot(x3[:,0],yex3,yex32)
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-a55893800c7b> in <module>
     28 
     29 ax.plot(x1[:,0],x1[:,1],x1[:,2])
---> 30 ax.plot(x1[:,0],yex1,yex12)
     31 ax.plot(x2[:,0],x2[:,1],x2[:,2])
     32 ax.plot(x2[:,0],yex2,yex22)

~\Downloads\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py in 
 plot(self, xs, ys, zdir, *args, **kwargs)
    1530         zs = np.broadcast_to(zs, len(xs))
    1531 
 -> 1532         lines = super().plot(xs, ys, *args, **kwargs)
    1533         for line in lines:
    1534             art3d.line_2d_to_3d(line, zs=zs, zdir=zdir)

~\Downloads\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in 
plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1664         """
   1665         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, 
mlines.Line2D._alias_map)
-> 1666         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1667         for line in lines:
   1668             self.add_line(line)

~\Downloads\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in 
__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    223                 this += args[0],
    224                 args = args[1:]
--> 225             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    226 
    227     def get_next_color(self):

~\Downloads\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in 
_plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    389             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])
    390 
--> 391         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    392 
    393         if self.command == 'plot':

~\Downloads\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in 
_xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    268         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    269             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first 
dimension, but "
--> 270                              "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, 
y.shape))
    271         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    272             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, 
but have "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (500,) 
and (1,)
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.polyfit` returns an array of coefficients:

```py
>>> np.polyfit(np.arange(4), np.arange(4), 1)
array([1.00000000e+00, 1.12255857e-16])
```

To turn this into a callable polynomial, use `np.poly1d` on the result:

```py
>>> p = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(np.arange(4), np.arange(4), 1))
>>> p(1)
1.0000000000000002
```

So in your project, change these lines:

```py
fit1 = np.polyfit(x1[:,0],x1[:,1],7)
# etc.
```

to

```py
fit1 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x1[:,0],x1[:,1],7))
# etc.
```

**Edit:** Your new error seems to stem from the fact that your extended axes have 2 dimensions each:

```py
extended1 = np.linspace(x1[-1,:], x1[-1,:] + 300, 1) # extended1.ndim == 2 !
extended2 = np.linspace(x2[-1,:], x2[-1,:] + 300, 1)
extended3 = np.linspace(x3[-1,:], x3[-1,:] + 300, 1)
```

If I understand your code correctly, this is what you want to do instead:

```py
extended1 = np.arange(x1[-1, 0], x1[-1, 0] + 300)
extended2 = np.arange(x2[-1, 0], x2[-1, 0] + 300)
extended3 = np.arange(x3[-1, 0], x3[-1, 0] + 300)
```

And further below:

```py
ax.plot(x1[:,0],x1[:,1],x1[:,2])
ax.plot(extended1,yex1,yex12)
ax.plot(x2[:,0],x2[:,1],x2[:,2])
ax.plot(extended2,yex2,yex22)
ax.plot(x3[:,0],x3[:,1],x3[:,2])
ax.plot(extended3,yex3,yex32)
```

Comment: After doing this, I get another error. Ill update the code above and include this error message.

Comment: So I changed the code, and I get another error message, which I'll provide above.

Comment: Found the mistake, see my last edit (the bottom two code boxes).